# Combine and reformat 2 files into a new files

Tags: linux, shell

I'm collection some of the output of the command and want to combine 2 output files into a new file.

Output sample

```
output1.txt
OBJECTNAME(TEST.OBJ.1) TYPE(LOCAL)
MESSAGE(20)
OBJECTNAME(TEST.OBJ.2) TYPE(LOCAL)
MESSAGE(30)
...

output2.txt
OBJECTNAME(TEST.OBJ.1) TYPE(MESSAGE)
TIME(16.00.00) DATE(2018-01-11)
OBJECTNAME(TEST.OBJ.2) TYPE(MESSAGE)
TIME(23.44.56) DATE(2019-06-11)
...
```

and my code is

```
MESSAGE=$(echo "DIS MESSAGE(*) MESSAGE")
MESSAGEINFO=$(echo "DIS MESSAGEINFO(*) TIME DATE")
echo "$MESSAGE" >> output1.txt
echo "$MESSAGEINFO" >> output2.txt
```

How do i do can make it to output3.txt like:

```
OBJECTNAME(TEST.OBJ.1) TYPE(LOCAL)
MESSAGE(20)
TIME(16.00.00) DATE(2018-01-11)
OBJECTNAME(TEST.OBJ.2) TYPE(LOCAL)
MESSAGE(30)
TIME(23.44.56) DATE(2019-06-11)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind loosing "TYPE(MESSAGE)" and "TYPE(MESSAGE)" completely this could be a starting point:

```
 diff -u2  <(sed 's/TYPE(LOCAL)//' output1.txt)  <(sed 's/TYPE(MESSAGE)//' output2.txt) | tr -d '+-' | sed -r '/^\s*$/d'
```

- <(sed ...) removes the TYPE(...) from the file to give a syncing point
- diff shows the difference between the files (using  OBJECTNAME(TEST.OBJ.XY) to sync 
  this outputs something with some +/- to signal the difference
- tr deletes all + and - charakters from the file. (if you have them somewhere on purpose a sed with 's/^+//' and 's/^-//' are better, but I am not that good in sed)
- the las sed removes empty lines

Outputs with upper input files:

```
 OBJECTNAME(TEST.OBJ.1)
MESSAGE(20)
TIME(16.00.00) DATE(20180111)
 OBJECTNAME(TEST.OBJ.2)
MESSAGE(30)
TIME(23.44.56) DATE(20190611)
```

Further clean up could be removing the space at begin with sed 's/^ //' but I don't want to stack another pipe.
For sure there may be a better looking way but this may be good enough. And if you like you could even add TYPE(LOCAL) back in after merging.

REMARK: This will only work if the structure / order of the file content is as shallow as in your example...